# Ubuntu Server: Boot Messages on terminal 7 (video) Why?

Tags: 12.04, boot, server, plymouth, udev

I use only text terminals in ubuntu server.

Especially at boot time :)

I've turned off plymouth splash screen and I get boot messages on terminal 1.
But after couple of messages, active terminal is swiching to terminal 7. (then messages with fsck and * Starting and * Stopping services) and then i'm switched back to terminal 1 with login prompt. Why?

I wan to to see all messages on terminal 1.
Why video terminal is even loaded?
Why messages are displayed there?

How to display everything on 1st terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this with a [kernel parameter](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/configure-kernel.html):

```
root=/dev/sda1 console=ttyS0,57600n8 console=tty1
```

will make all messages go to tty1. You need to add this to [Grub](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/configure-kernel-grub.html) and [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter) explains that.

Comment: I've added:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty1"
in /etc/default/grub
and then:
sudo update-grub && sudo reboot

And it Works! Thank You!